# Setting Parse Cloud Code Function as a Destination URL

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, webhooks

I am working with a payment processing API that uses webhooks to verify payments. The webhook endpoint is supposed to be the server's URL.

Is it possible to set a Parse Cloud Code function as a webhook endpoint? What would the URL look like?

Or do I need to set up a separate server for this?